# Is there a way to quickly & easily enable/disable a page's header & footer in Firefox just like in Google Chrome?

Tags: firefox, printing, headers, footers

There are many times in which I won't want any header and footer to be printed on pages that I am printing, but there are also many times when I will want them. With Google Chrome, this is very fast because I simply press Ctrl + P to print, which brings up the browser's Print Preview screen, I need to then scroll down and click on More Settings, and then uncheck the box next to "Headers and footers". Ideally, it would be nice if I didn't have to scroll and also click on More Settings.

Anyhow, in this manner, I can keep my same header and footer that are created and simply have to turn them on or off.

With Firefox on the other hand, I need to go File > Page Setup or File > Print Preview > Page Setup, then go to Margins & Header / Footer, go the the Headers and Footers section below, and then select blank for all the areas of a page I have headers and footers setup. To restore it, I need to do the same procedure and then change the blank options to the types of headers and footers I had before--title, page numbers, etc.

This is very annoying and time consuming. I wish there was just a way to check and uncheck a box like one can with Google Chrome. So is there a way to accomplish this?

Right now my needs are only to either have no headers and footers or to have the same set of headers and footers on / present. It would however be great to also have different headers and footers profiles--i.e. title and page numbers sometimes, other times URL and dates only, other times URL and page numbers, and so on.

Comment: Removed software rec portion.